# Most efficient way to to find most expensive recent order

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to find most recent and expensive purchase by customer. I have four tables customers,orders,order details and product code. All accounts are unique by emailaddress.

Error The multi-part identifier "cx.EmailAddress" could not be bound

```
SELECT c.EmailAddress,
       o.BillingFirstName AS WC_FirstName,
       o2.LatestOrder
FROM Customers c
JOIN orders o ON o.customerid = c.customerid
JOIN( SELECT
            cx.EmailAddress,
            MAX(o.OrderID) AS LatestOrder
      FROM Customers AS cx
      JOIN Orders o ON o.customerid = cx.customerid
      WHERE o.OrderStatus <> 'CANCELLED' AND o.OrderDate > '09/01/2017 00:00'
      GROUP BY EmailAddress) AS o2 on o2.EmailAddress = cx.EmailAddress
 GROUP BY c.EmailAddress,o.BillingFirstName
```

UPDATE Tried it in another way too but still gets error : The multi-part identifier "c.EmailAddress" could not be bound.

```
SELECT 
    c.EmailAddress,
    c.CustomerID,
    o.OrderDate,
    p.Google_Gender,
    p.Google_Age_Group ,
    p.productprice AS Product_Price
FROM 
    Customers c
JOIN 
    orders o ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         c.EmailAddress,
         MAX(o.OrderID) AS LatestOrder
     FROM
         Orders o, Customers c 
     WHERE
         o.OrderStatus <> 'CANCELLED' AND
         o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
     GROUP BY
         c.EmailAddress) AS o2 ON o2.EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         od.*,
         c.EmailAddress,
         row_number() over (partition BY c.EmailAddress
                            ORDER BY od.ProductPrice DESC, o.OrderDate DESC)  AS seqnum
     FROM 
         OrderDetails od
     JOIN 
         Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
     JOIN 
         Customers c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
     JOIN
         (SELECT 
              c.EmailAddress,
              MAX(o.OrderID) AS LatestOrder
          FROM
              Orders o , Customers c
          WHERE
              o.OrderStatus <> 'CANCELLED' AND
              o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
          GROUP BY
              c.EmailAddress) AS o2 ON o2.EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress
    WHERE 
        o.OrderID = o2.LatestOrder) od ON od.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                                       AND seqnum = 1
JOIN 
    Products_Joined p ON od.ProductCode = p.ProductCode
FULL JOIN 
    (SELECT p.ProductCode, p.ProductName FROM Products_Joined AS p) AS p2 ON p2.ProductCode = p.Google_Age_Group
WHERE
    AND o.PaymentAmount <> 0
    AND o.OrderID = o2.LatestOrder
GROUP BY 
    c.EmailAddress, o.OrderDate, c.CustomerID, p.productprice,
    p.Google_Age_Group, p.Google_Gender, p.Google_Pattern,
    p.Google_Size, od.ProductName, p.ProductName, p2.productname,
    p.productcode
ORDER BY 
    o.OrderDate DESC, MAX(od.ProductPrice) DESC;
```

Comment: You should include your tables' structure if you need help with your query. You didn't specify any amount field and you are just getting the latest order, not the most expensive one.

Comment: I suggest you do NOT repeat table aliases so you don't get confusing error messages. You have a lot of subqueries and always use `c` as alias for Customers. Are you sure you want a FULL (OUTER) JOIN there?

Answer (score 1):

You have that error because `cx` is an internal alias inside the `o2` query. So you should probably change that JOIN condition for this one:

`AS o2 on o2.EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress`

This way you join your `o2` email address with the one from Customers directly.

Just for the sake of performance, it would be better if you join customers by `CustomerID`, like you do in your first join, instead of by email.

Finally, you are doing the MAX of OrderID, which will most likely return the most recent order. Having that in mind, you should probably change your query to something like this (I'm guessing `Amount` is the name of the field):

```
SELECT c.EmailAddress,
       o.BillingFirstName AS WC_FirstName,
       MostExpensiveOrderId = o.OrderId,
       MostExpensiveOrderAmount = o.Amount
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        CustomerID,
        MAX(Amount)
    FROM Orders
    WHERE OrderStatus <> 'CANCELLED' AND OrderDate > '09/01/2017 00:00'
    GROUP BY CustomerID
) AS omax ON omax.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID AND o.Amount = omax.Amount
ORDER BY c.EmailAddress, o.BillingFirstName
```

Note that you don't need the Customers table in the inner query. Also note that this way you may get more than one row per customer if the highest value is shared with more than one order.

Comment: I have updated the query with other way i am trying but still getting that couldnot bound error. And the customers are unique by email address and not by customers thats why i am trying to do a join on that, but still getting errors

Comment: CustomerID is not unique? I hope that's not what you meant. Joining by ID, especially if it's PK, is always faster than by a varchar field. And also clearer.